# Why is format(str(var)) giving me an Attribute Error for my os.system

Tags: python, macos, attributeerror, os.system

I'm trying to make a Python script that connects me to a VPN Server 'number' (with this number as a variable)

I wrote:

```
import os
VPNServer = 0
VPNServer += 1
os.system("networksetup -connectpppoeservice 'VPNServer {servernumber}'").format(servernumber = str(VPNServer))
print("→ Successfully connected to", "VPNServer", VPNServer)
```

But everytime I try to run it, the console gives me an **AttributeError**

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'format'
```

I don't understand it because I took the string version of the variable

If someone could help, it would be super cool

**I'm on macOS and I'm using Python 3.8.1**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the snippet you provided, you write

```
os.system('<some string>').format(args)
```

You are making the `format` call on the return value of [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.html#os.system), which happens to be an integer. This is identical to writing e.g.

```
5.format(args)
```

Since `int` objects have no attribute `format`, you get the `AttributeError` you described.

What you want to write is

```
os.system('<some string>'.format(args))
```

In this specific case, your snippet should resemble

```
os.system(
    "networksetup -connectpppoeservice 'VPNServer {servernumber}'"
       .format(servernumber=VPNServer)
)
```

Note that the `str(VPNServer)` call is superfluous, since `format` will autmatically call the `__str__` method of the object provided.